# Finite dimensionality and maximal ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, group-schemes

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and let $A$ be a finitely generated commutative $k$-algebra.  Is the following equivalence true?

> A is finite-dimensional over $k$ if and only if $A$ has finitely many maximal ideals.

The context of the question comes from considering $A$ as the coordinate (Hopf) algebra of some affine group scheme of finite type, $G$, over $k$.  We say that $G$ is finite if $A$ is finite-dimensional, so I'm wondering if this is the same as saying that there are only finitely many $k$-points of $G$, that is, finitely many maximal ideals of $A$.

Comment: @rschwieb: Yes.  I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forward implication is always true; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artinian_ring#Commutative_Artinian_rings.

The backward implication is false if we do not assume $A$ is a finite-type $k$-algebra; e.g. $A$ could be an infinite degree field extension of $k$, or something like $k[[x]]$.

If we do assume $A$ is a finite-type $k$-algebra, then $Spec(A)$ is a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^n_{/k}$ for some $n$. Since there are only finitely many maximal ideals, each component of this subscheme is $0$-dimensional, and so $A$ is Artinian (see the above link).