# Finite Dimensional $k$-Algebra has finitely many Maximal Ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-varieties

I have a question about an argument used in Tamas Szamuely's "Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups" in following excerpt (see page 102):

We start with affine variety $X$ of dimension $n$. According Noether Normalization Lemma there exist an injection $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{A}^n_k) = k[x_1,...,x_n] \to  \mathcal{O}(X)$.

The contravariant category equivalence between affine varieties over $k$ and that of finitely generated
reduced $k$-algebras induce a surjection $\phi: X \to \mathbb{A}^n_k$.

Let $M_p=(x_1-a_1,..., x_n -a_n)$ an maximal ideal of $\mathbb{A}^n_k$.

I have following two questions:

1. Why is the fiber $\mathcal{O}(X)/M_P \mathcal{O}(X)$ a ***finite dimensional $k$-algebra***?
2. If 1. holds: Why does it imply that a finite dimensional $k$-algebra has finitely many maximal ideals?

Comment: $k[x]$ is not a finite dimensional $k$-algebra.

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511597/finite-dimensionality-and-maximal-ideals?rq=1

Comment: @DistractedKerl:  ah yes I see the dimension is not the Krull dimension but the vector space dimension. I deleted this false conter example

Comment: @DistractedKerl: ok so 2. holds because it's Artin. btw: DO you have a nice reference for the proof that  a finite dimensional $k$-algebra is Artin? Futhermore do you see why $\mathcal{O}(X)/M_P \mathcal{O}(X)$ has this property?

Comment: 1. is (one version) of the Nullstellensatz (more precisely Zariskis lemma: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_lemma ) 2. Is the link in the first comment. Hope that helps you :)

Comment: @DistractedKerl: ad 1: Do you mean this in sense that $Frac(\mathcal{O}(X)/M_P \mathcal{O}(X))$ is a finite $k$-extension?

Comment: The quotient is already a field. :)

Comment: @DistractedKerl: Why is the quotient $\mathcal{O}(X)/M_P \mathcal{O}(X)$ a field?

Comment: @DistractedKerl: ...hmm guess that there could exist some statement that for a finite map maximal ideals are mapped to maximal ideals

Comment: Part 1 is that finite morphisms are stable under fiber products (and taking the fiber is a fiber product) and part 2 is well-known, and could be found easily by searching: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919463/a-finite-dimensional-algebra-over-a-field-has-only-finitely-many-prime-ideals-an . Please try harder to find answers on your own before coming here next time - most basic results like these are already up somewhere on MSE.